# How to separate a dictionary by one key in Python while also parsing the data?

Tags: python

I have the following information stored in a dictionary called conversation_counter. Due the project manager's instructions, I can't share the whole code, but this is me iterating through it.

```
{'conversation_id': '4850dd66-05b9-43e9-b546-e4976c9c29b6', 'dialog_counter': '1', 'agent_text': 'Hey welcome to Hatch realty, before we start our conversation, can I start by asking your name?', 'customer_input': '', 'customer_name': 'Brandon', 'customer_intention': 'sell', 'customer_property': 'house'}
{'conversation_id': '4850dd66-05b9-43e9-b546-e4976c9c29b6', 'dialog_counter': '2', 'agent_text': 'Great, thanks David. Is there something I can help you with, or what brought you to our site?', 'customer_input': 'My name is David', 'customer_name': 'David', 'customer_intention': 'buy', 'customer_property': 'house'}
{'conversation_id': '4850dd66-05b9-43e9-b546-e4976c9c29b6', 'dialog_counter': '3', 'agent_text': 'Of course, when would you like to move?', 'customer_input': 'I want to buy a house', 'customer_name': 'Brandon', 'customer_intention': 'buy', 'customer_property': 'house'}
{'conversation_id': '4850dd66-05b9-43e9-b546-e4976c9c29b6', 'dialog_counter': '4', 'agent_text': 'Do you have a specific property address?', 'customer_input': 'This summer', 'customer_name': 'Brandon', 'customer_intention': 'buy', 'customer_property': 'house'}
{'conversation_id': '4850dd66-05b9-43e9-b546-e4976c9c29b6', 'dialog_counter': '5', 'agent_text': 'Can I get your email address and phone number so I can have someone reach out to you?', 'customer_input': "No I don't.", 'customer_name': 'David', 'customer_intention': 'buy', 'customer_property': 'house'}
{'conversation_id': 'dbec6faa-16cb-416a-8653-ffc36174ecee', 'dialog_counter': '1', 'agent_text': 'Hey welcome to Hatch realty, before we start our conversation, can I start by asking your name?', 'customer_input': '', 'customer_name': 'David', 'customer_intention': 'buy', 'customer_property': 'house'}
{'conversation_id': 'dbec6faa-16cb-416a-8653-ffc36174ecee', 'dialog_counter': '2', 'agent_text': 'Great, thanks Brandon. Is there something I can help you with, or what brought you to our site?', 'customer_input': 'My name is Brandon', 'customer_name': 'Brandon', 'customer_intention': '', 'customer_property': ''}
{'conversation_id': 'dbec6faa-16cb-416a-8653-ffc36174ecee', 'dialog_counter': '3', 'agent_text': 'Of course, Do you need to be out by a certain date or is your timeframe open?', 'customer_input': 'I want to sell a house', 'customer_name': 'Brandon', 'customer_intention': 'sell', 'customer_property': 'house'}
{'conversation_id': 'dbec6faa-16cb-416a-8653-ffc36174ecee', 'dialog_counter': '4', 'agent_text': 'Do you have a specific property address?', 'customer_input': "It's open", 'customer_name': 'David', 'customer_intention': 'buy', 'customer_property': 'house'}
{'conversation_id': 'dbec6faa-16cb-416a-8653-ffc36174ecee', 'dialog_counter': '5', 'agent_text': 'Can I get your email address and phone number so I can have someone reach out to you?', 'customer_input': "No I don't", 'customer_name': 'David', 'customer_intention': 'buy', 'customer_property': 'house'}
```

As you can see, there are only two different conversation_ids (first value). The conversations won't always have 5 counts (see dialog_counter), so how do I either 1) find the highest dialog_counter per conversation_id OR create a separate dictionary for each of the conversation_id.

Here's what I have so far, but it only contains one dictionary which makes sense because I'm hard updating the dictionary so it cancels the first one.

```
conversationID = ""
data = {
    "conversation_id": "",
    "customer_name": "",
    "customer_intention": "",
    "customer_property": ""
        }
for convo in conversation_counter:
    conversationID = convo['conversation_id']
    for conversations in conversationID:
        data["conversation_id"] = convo['conversation_id']
        if customer_name != "":
            data["customer_name"] = convo['customer_name']
        if customer_intention != "":
            data["customer_intention"] = convo['customer_intention']
        if customer_property != "":
            data["customer_property"] = convo['customer_property']

print(data)
```

The output is exactly what I want, but only gives me one entry. I think the easiest way to do this is find the highest dialog counter but I don't know how to do that in a for loop with separate entries.

```
{'conversation_id': 'dbec6faa-16cb-416a-8653-ffc36174ecee', 'customer_name': 'Brandon', 'customer_intention': 'sell', 'customer_property': 'house'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier when you break it down into steps:

1. Aggregate the messages into conversations
2. sort the conversations
3. get the last message from each one.

```py
from typing import Dict, List
import pprint

data: List[Dict[str, str]] = [
    {'conversation_id': '4850dd66-05b9-43e9-b546-e4976c9c29b6', 'dialog_counter': '1', 'agent_text': 'Hey welcome to Hatch realty, before we start our conversation, can I start by asking your name?', 'customer_input': '', 'customer_name': 'Brandon', 'customer_intention': 'sell', 'customer_property': 'house'}
   ,{'conversation_id': '4850dd66-05b9-43e9-b546-e4976c9c29b6', 'dialog_counter': '2', 'agent_text': 'Great, thanks David. Is there something I can help you with, or what brought you to our site?', 'customer_input': 'My name is David', 'customer_name': 'David', 'customer_intention': 'buy', 'customer_property': 'house'}
   ,{'conversation_id': '4850dd66-05b9-43e9-b546-e4976c9c29b6', 'dialog_counter': '3', 'agent_text': 'Of course, when would you like to move?', 'customer_input': 'I want to buy a house', 'customer_name': 'Brandon', 'customer_intention': 'buy', 'customer_property': 'house'}
   ,{'conversation_id': '4850dd66-05b9-43e9-b546-e4976c9c29b6', 'dialog_counter': '4', 'agent_text': 'Do you have a specific property address?', 'customer_input': 'This summer', 'customer_name': 'Brandon', 'customer_intention': 'buy', 'customer_property': 'house'}
   ,{'conversation_id': '4850dd66-05b9-43e9-b546-e4976c9c29b6', 'dialog_counter': '5', 'agent_text': 'Can I get your email address and phone number so I can have someone reach out to you?', 'customer_input': "No I don't.", 'customer_name': 'David', 'customer_intention': 'buy', 'customer_property': 'house'}
   ,{'conversation_id': 'dbec6faa-16cb-416a-8653-ffc36174ecee', 'dialog_counter': '1', 'agent_text': 'Hey welcome to Hatch realty, before we start our conversation, can I start by asking your name?', 'customer_input': '', 'customer_name': 'David', 'customer_intention': 'buy', 'customer_property': 'house'}
   ,{'conversation_id': 'dbec6faa-16cb-416a-8653-ffc36174ecee', 'dialog_counter': '2', 'agent_text': 'Great, thanks Brandon. Is there something I can help you with, or what brought you to our site?', 'customer_input': 'My name is Brandon', 'customer_name': 'Brandon', 'customer_intention': '', 'customer_property': ''}
   ,{'conversation_id': 'dbec6faa-16cb-416a-8653-ffc36174ecee', 'dialog_counter': '3', 'agent_text': 'Of course, Do you need to be out by a certain date or is your timeframe open?', 'customer_input': 'I want to sell a house', 'customer_name': 'Brandon', 'customer_intention': 'sell', 'customer_property': 'house'}
   ,{'conversation_id': 'dbec6faa-16cb-416a-8653-ffc36174ecee', 'dialog_counter': '4', 'agent_text': 'Do you have a specific property address?', 'customer_input': "It's open", 'customer_name': 'David', 'customer_intention': 'buy', 'customer_property': 'house'}
   ,{'conversation_id': 'dbec6faa-16cb-416a-8653-ffc36174ecee', 'dialog_counter': '5', 'agent_text': 'Can I get your email address and phone number so I can have someone reach out to you?', 'customer_input': "No I don't", 'customer_name': 'David', 'customer_intention': 'buy', 'customer_property': 'house'}
]

conversations:Dict[str, List[Dict[str, str]]] = dict() # typing indicator just for IDE nice-to-haves
# group conversations by conversation id
for message in data:
    cid = message.get('conversation_id')
    if not cid:
        continue
    if cid not in conversations:
        conversations[cid] = list()
    conversations[cid].append(message)

# sort each conversation by message dialog counter
conversations = {
    cid: sorted(conversation, key=(lambda message:message.get('dialog_counter')))
    for cid, conversation in conversations.items()
}

# get the last message in each conversation
last_messages = [conversation[-1] for conversation in conversations.values()]

pprint.pprint(last_messages)
```

---

I forgot the output:

```
[{'agent_text': 'Can I get your email address and phone number so I can have '
                'someone reach out to you?',
  'conversation_id': '4850dd66-05b9-43e9-b546-e4976c9c29b6',
  'customer_input': "No I don't.",
  'customer_intention': 'buy',
  'customer_name': 'David',
  'customer_property': 'house',
  'dialog_counter': '5'},
 {'agent_text': 'Can I get your email address and phone number so I can have '
                'someone reach out to you?',
  'conversation_id': 'dbec6faa-16cb-416a-8653-ffc36174ecee',
  'customer_input': "No I don't",
  'customer_intention': 'buy',
  'customer_name': 'David',
  'customer_property': 'house',
  'dialog_counter': '5'}]
```

Comment: It worked! I have no idea what most of this means but I need to learn. Thank you so much.